# Is there a Python equivalent for Scala's Option or Either?

Tags: python, scala, functional-programming

I really enjoy using the Option and Either monads in Scala. Are there any equivalent for these things in Python? If there aren't, then what is the pythonic way of handling errors or "absence of value" without throwing exceptions?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The pythonic way for a function to say "I am not defined at this point" is to raise an exception.

```
>>> int("blarg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'blarg'

>>> dict(foo=5)['bar']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
KeyError: 'bar'

>>> 1 / 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

This is, in part, because there's no (generally useful) static type checker for python.  A Python function *cannot* syntactically state, at compile time, that it has a particular codomain;  there's no way to force callers to match all of the cases in the function's return type.

If you prefer, you can write (unpythonically) a `Maybe` wrapper:

```
class Maybe(object):
    def get_or_else(self, default):
        return self.value if isinstance(self, Just) else default

class Just(Maybe):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

class Nothing(Maybe):
    pass
```

But I would not do this, unless you're trying to port something from Scala to Python without changing much.

Comment: One may also use `None` vs. `<actual value you want>` and enforce it with discipline.

Comment: Hi @SingleNegationElimination, i understand your point about absence of static types, but still Option (and other Monads) gives you a powerful abstraction to reason about your code! Even if you won't get type check you still get a hint that value, in case of option, can be missing, and do something to recover from failure!

Answer (score 23):

You can play with typing package (Python 3.6.9). Using following makes type checker happy

```
from typing import Optional, Union


def parse_int(s: str) -> Optional[int]:
    try:
        return int(s)
    except:
        return None


print('-- optional --')
print(parse_int('123'))
print(parse_int('a'))


def parse_int2(s: str) -> Union[str, int]:
    try:
        return int(s)
    except Exception as e:
        return f'Error during parsing "{s}": {e}'


print('-- either --')
print(parse_int2('123'))
print(parse_int2('a'))
```

Result

```
-- optional --
123
None
-- either --
123
Error during parsing "a": invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a'
```

If you want to add  monadic behaviour to `Either` you can try this

```
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Callable

A = TypeVar('A')
B = TypeVar('B')
C = TypeVar('C')

Either = NewType('Either', Union['Left[A]', 'Right[C]'])


class Left(Generic[A]):
    def __init__(self, value: A):
        self.__value = value

    def get(self) -> A:
        raise Exception('it is left')

    def get_left(self) -> A:
        return self.__value

    def flat_map(self, f: Callable[[B], Either]) -> Either:
        return self

    def map(self, f: Callable[[B], C]) -> Either:
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Left({self.__value})'
```

and right type

```
class Right(Generic[B]):
    def __init__(self, value: B):
        self.__value = value

    def flat_map(self, f: Callable[[B], Either]) -> Either:
        return f(self.__value)

    def map(self, f: Callable[[B], C]) -> Either:
        return Right(f(self.__value))

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Right({self.__value})'


def parse_int(s: str) -> Union[Left[str], Right[int]]:
    try:
        return Right(int(s))
    except Exception as e:
        return Left(f'Error during parsing {s}: {e}')

def divide(x: int) -> Union[Left[str], Right[int]]:
    return Right(4 / x) if x != 0 else Left('zero !!!')

print(parse_int('1').map(lambda x: x * 2))
print(parse_int('a').map(lambda x: x * 2))
print(parse_int('2').flat_map(divide))
print(parse_int('0').flat_map(divide))
```

Result

```
Right(2)
Left(Error during parsing a: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'a')
Right(2.0)
Left(zero !!!)
```

Comment: Union cannot be used as param for NewType

Answer (score 12):

In python, for an absence of value, the variable is None, so you can do it this way.

```
vars = None

vars = myfunction()

if vars is None:
     print 'No value!'
else:
     print 'Value!'
```

or even just check if a value is present like this

```
if vars is not None:
     print vars
```

Comment: Why is this voted down? It makes an important point that anything is nullable in Python because Python is not statically type-checked. I'd use `None` in Python the same way I'd use `None` in Scala, but Scala can verify that I don't use `None` in arithmetic, while Python lets me make this mistake all the time.

Comment: I voted down because the answer is very poor in terms of the question. The Option pattern in scala refers to a pattern Called 'Null Object Pattern' and the intention is to avoid the if statement

Comment: This is the simplest and most Pythonic answer, in my opinion. While I think highly of the option pattern in Scala and Rust (for example), but for Python, I think this commenter says it best: "One may also use None vs. <actual value you want> and enforce it with discipline. – Malcolm May 2 '17 at 21:00"

Comment: @LuisKarlos Under the hood there is if statement anyway. Option type is nothing but syntactic sugar. You can easily write OptionType function in any language.

Comment: I vote up because this is what I was looking for. (each language has its strengths, Scala has a cool compiler for having a cool Option pattern ... well, Python has simplicity for quick prototyping and with that a simple None, cool for me too)

Answer (score 12):

`mypy` adds type definitions and type checking (not at runtime) over regular Python. They have an `Optional`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Optional. More here https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#rationale-and-goals. Intellij has plugin support which makes it all very professional and smooth.

Comment: `mypy`'s `Optional` is only a *type annotation* only, meaning that it can be used like this "def foo(arg: Optional[int]) -> Optional[str]: ...` but it cannot be instantiated, namely `Optional("foo")` throws an error.

Comment: In Python, `Optional[T]` is just sugar for `Union[None, T]`. This is weak compared to Scala. For example, this means that you can't differentiate between an empty `Optional` and a non-empty `Optional` containing `None`. Also, there can't be tools like map or iter for `Optional`. And `Optional[Optional[T]]` is also `Union[None, T]`.

Answer (score 6):

I realize this is pretty late to the party but I came to this page on top of google before deciding to implement it so maybe I can help others googling with this. I implemented it, you can get it from pypi as `pyther-maybe`, it implements both Either and Maybe with Maybe as a special subclass of Either. This example should explain how it works:

```
import sys
from pyther_maybe import *

def save_div ( x, y ):
    if y == 0:
        return nothing() # alias of Maybe()
    else:
        return value(x / y) # alias of Maybe(x / y)

float_test = save_div(1.0, 3.0)

assert isinstance(float_test, Maybe)

if float_test: #nothing tests as false:
    float = float_test() # calling the container with no arguments returns its value
else:
    sys.exit("something went wrong")

print float

# or if you want to encode a reason:

def save_div ( x, y ):
    if y == 0:
        return left("You can't divide by zero, silly") # alias of Either(left=...)
    else:
        return right(x / y) # alis of Either(...)

float_test = save_div(4.2, 0.0)

assert isinstance(float_test, Either)

def fake_exit ( string ):
    print "We would have exited with:"
    print string
    return "Whatever value"

if float_test:
    # these two are te same
    float = float_test()
    float = float_test.right()
else:
    fake_exit(float_test.left())

# or in a shorter and more pleasant format
# does the same as above
float = float_test.extract(fake_exit)

print float # prints "Whatever value"

# Also, these containers are mutable:

box = nothing()

try:
    print box() # raises exception
except RightEitherException:
    print "We caught an exception"

def change_box():
    box(4)

change_box()
print box() # 4
```

It has more features than that, some of which are pretty useless in practise (it's also an iterator for instance and has subscript notation like `pyther_maybe.either(x)[pyther_maybe.Right] == x`.

Answer (score 4):

Try This:

```
from monad import Monad

class Either(Monad):
  # pure :: a -> Either a
  @staticmethod
  def pure(value):
    return Right(value)

  # flat_map :: # Either a -> (a -> Either b) -> Either b
  def flat_map(self, f):
    if self.is_left:
      return self
    else:
      return f(self.value)

class Left(Either):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
    self.is_left = True

class Right(Either):
  def __init__(self, value):
    self.value = value
self.is_left = False
```

Answer (score 3):

A list that happens to always be of length zero or one fulfills some of the same goals as optional/maybe types.  You won't get the benefits of static typing in Python, but you'll probably get a run-time error even on the happy path if you write code that tries to use the "maybe" without explicitly "unwrapping" it.

Answer (score 1):

Natively, Python has a Literal Type Optional but it's not the same. Alternatively this is a representation of the Either data type for python 3.

https://gist.github.com/MatteoGuadrini/98e79a9ab2bd6ae5badc41df89cfe338

Answer (score 1):

`pip install either`

The library was created in 2012, its Development status is: Stable, according to https://pypi.org/project/either/.

Answer (score 1):

There is a package called Pymonad that implements option types as maybe and an either type as well as other functional ideas such as a wrapper for currying, monads, monoids, and others.

General Details
https://pypi.org/project/PyMonad/
Reference
https://jasondelaat.github.io/pymonad_docs/reference/pymonad.html

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because this library provides Maybe and Either which is closest from all answers here to the "Scala's Option or Either" in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

## You can write your own `Optional` implement

```
from __future__ import annotations

from typing import *

T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")


class Option(Generic[T]):
    _value: Optional[T]

    @classmethod
    def ofNullable(cls, value: Optional[T]) -> Option[T]:
        option = cls()
        option._value = value
        return option

    @classmethod
    def of(cls, value: Optional[T]) -> Option[T]:
        assert value is not None
        return cls.ofNullable(value)

    @classmethod
    def empty(cls) -> Option[T]:
        return cls.ofNullable(None)

    def isPresent(self) -> bool:
        return self._value is not None

    def ifPresent(self, consumer: Callable[[T], Any]) -> None:
        if self._value is not None:
            consumer(self._value)

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self._value

    def orElse(self, other: T) -> T:
        return self._value if self._value is not None else other

    def orElseGet(self, other: Callable[[], T]) -> T:
        return self._value if self._value is not None else other()

    def orElseThrow(self, exceptionSupplier: Callable[[], BaseException]):
        if self._value is not None:
            return self._value
        else:
            raise exceptionSupplier()

    def filter(self, predicate: Callable[[T], bool]) -> Option[T]:
        if predicate(self):
            return self
        return self.__class__.empty()

    def map(self, mapper: Callable[[T], U]) -> Option[U]:
        if self._value is not None:
            return self.__class__.of(mapper(self._value))
        return self.__class__.empty()

    def flatMap(self, mapper: Callable[[T], Option[U]]) -> Option[U]:
        if self._value is not None:
            return mapper(self._value)
        return self.__class__.empty()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"<Option:{self._value}>"

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"<Option:{repr(self._value)}>"

    def __eq__(self, other: Union[T, Any]):
        if isinstance(other, Option):
            return self._value == other._value
        return False
```

## Or use a 3rd `Optional` library

### IceSpringRealOptional

**Real** `Optional` type in `python`, not `@Nullable` annotation.

### Official sites

- Home: https://baijifeilong.github.io/2022/01/09/ice-spring-real-optional/index.html
- Github: https://github.com/baijifeilong/IceSpringRealOptional
- PyPI: https://pypi.org/project/IceSpringRealOptional

### Features

- All `Java 8` style `Optional` API support
- All `Generic Type` annotation support

### Install

- PyPI: `pip install IceSpringRealOptional`

### Usage

```py
from IceSpringRealOptional import Option

option = Option.ofNullable("CommonSense")
print("{}: isPresent={}".format(option, option.isPresent()))
print("{}: value={}".format(option, option.get()))
option.ifPresent(lambda x: print(f"{x} exist"))
print("{}'s length: {}".format(option, option.map(len)))

empty = Option.empty()
print(empty.orElse("{} is empty".format(empty)))
print(empty.orElseGet(lambda: "{} is empty again".format(empty)))

try:
    Option.empty().orElseThrow(lambda: RuntimeError("Unlucky"))
except RuntimeError as e:
    print("Runtime error caught: {}".format(e))
```

#### Example Output

```
<Option:CommonSense>: isPresent=True
<Option:CommonSense>: value=CommonSense
CommonSense exist
<Option:CommonSense>'s length: <Option:11>
<Option:None> is empty
<Option:None> is empty again
Runtime error caught: Unlucky
```